# Laravel 5 dynamic form validation

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, dynamic, laravel-5

Does anyone have any idea how to perform validation on something like the dynamic form below?

```
<input type="text" name="candidates[0][candidate_number]" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="candidates[0][givennames]" value=""/>

<input type="text" name="candidates[1][candidate_number]" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="candidates[1][givennames]" value=""/>
```

I feel like I have tried everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [form requests](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation), it's pretty easy. In your form request class:

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [];

    foreach($this->input('candidates') as $key => $value) {
        $rules["candidates.{$key}.candidate_number"] = ['required', 'numeric'];
        $rules["candidates.{$key}. givennames"] = ['required'];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. Just need to customize those error messages now! :)

Comment: @0w3n86 You can take the same approach with the form request's `messages()` function. Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry I spoke to soon! Now when I actually enter any data into the input it returns the error:
The candidates[0][candidate number] field is required.

Comment: Sorry I should still keep your answer as accepted as it did work. I think the problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: If you `dd($this->all())` within your `rules()` function you can see what data it's seting.

Comment: "candidates" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "candidate_number" => "987654"
      "givennames" => "John"

Comment: I think I have to update the protected  $fillable section in my in my candidate model ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
foreach($request->input('array') as $i => $value) {
    $rules['array.'.$i] = 'validation rules here';
}
```

Your rules should look like:

```
array.0 => 'rule'
array.1 => 'rule'
```

and so on.